# 'int' object is not subscriptable while resizing image with PIL in Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I recieve this error when trying to compile my code.
[image]

I know that the .size is an array though, because it would return (1200, 800) for H and W - and I only want one of these. I have looked through syntax examples and tried using parenths and nothing as well. Also, the other answers to this question on StackOverflow do not address my issues.

Please help! I am not usually a Python programmer.

Thank you.

EDIT: I apologize for posting a screenshot instead of code

Comment: Please, next time don't post an image but copy and paste your code.

Comment: you can do `height, width = img.size`

Comment: The question title says `PIL` but the code says `cv2`, I'm sure that's your problem. Don't assume they're the same, they're not even close.

Comment: When editing the question you should have copy/pasted the code from the left window (in the screenshot) ant the traceback from the right, instead of apologizing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*cv2.imread* (check [[OpenCV.Docs]: Getting Started with Images](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)) returns an [[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). As seen, its size attribute is an *int*, which is a scalar type, so you can't index it.

If you want to get the image width and height, you should use the ***shape*** attribute instead:

> ```py
> >>> img = cv2.imread("c:\\valmand.png")
> >>> type(img)
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
> >>> img.size
> 1493331
> >>> img.shape
> (799, 623, 3)
> >>> img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
> (799, 623)
> >>> img.shape[0] * img.shape[1] * img.shape[2]
> 1493331
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. Much appreciated, Cristi.

Comment: You should edit the question (and paste the code and stacktrace) to avoid downvotes (and even it being closed) in the future.If you find it difficult, just paste the text, I'll format it.